# Class "MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager" not found when called subsequently

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

so I've got this small webhook endpoint that get's called with JSON data and then stores this data into a remote MongoDB Atlas database.
Everything is happening locally, except from the database executions.

- **Environment**: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- **Service**: Apache2
- **PHP**: 8.0.3
- **MongoDB**: 1.8.0 // Installed via composer, required in composer.json, extension enabled in php.ini

To simulate these requests, I've locally built a PHP script `sender.php` that makes a POST request via curls to my locally installed webserver to my recieving file `listener.php`.

When I execute the `listener.php` directly it works fine, all data goes through and get's written into the remote MongoDB Atlas database.
But when it get's called from my webhook file `sender.php` I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager" not found
```

Here is the most basic code-files, with which I can reproduce the error.

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.8"
    }
}
```

**sender.php**

```
$url = "http://localhost/listener.php";

$data = array(
    "id" => "12345",
    "title" => "Test",
    "status" => "updated"
);

$ch = curl_init($url);

$payload = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**listener.php**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$incomingWebhookData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

function submitToDb($database, $collection, $data)
{
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(
        'mongodb+srv://<user_placeholder>:<password_placeholder>@<cluster_placeholder>.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    );

    $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;


    $doc = [
        "_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID,
        "data_id" => $data->id,
        "title" => $data->title,
        "status" => $data->status,
    ];

    $bulk->insert($doc);

    $manager->executeBulkWrite($database . "." . $collection, $bulk);

}

$database = "webhook_data";
$collection = "internal";
submitToDb($database, $collection, $incomingWebhookData);
```

- I've tried namespacing the MongoDB Class in the `listener.php` -> same thing
- Restarting all service, dumping the autoload, reinstalling everything from scratch -> same thing

What global mishap am I missing?

Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that my local webserver (Apache2) used a different PHP-CLI than my development environment and therefore all the enabled extensions and configurations had no effect as soon as the request got parsed to the webserver.

Use docker kids.